# Placing an infobox (overlay) manually near a pointer (overlay) on OpenStreetMaps

Tags: javascript, typescript, maps, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am using some "advanced" pointers and infoboxes on my OpenStreetMap. Those markers and infoboxes is made as overlayes containing HTML. It is all working fine :-) But I am having a problem. I am always showing the infoboxes below the pointer (using lat and long for the pointer), but when a pointer i places near the top of the map, then I need to show the infoBox below the pointer. I have tried to solve that issue by multiplying the latitude with a number, but the number is depended on zoom level and latitude.

So my question is, is there a way to calculate a point, so it is always placed in the same visual distance from the pointer, on behalf of a given lat and long (the pointer)?

Comment: I thing If ypu change the zoom level may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for you reply. 
The problem appears when the user use the zoom function?

Comment: on the click event of the marker to display the infobox

Comment: I am really sorry, but I don't understand the solution you are suggesting.

Comment: I mean on the click event of the marker change the zoom level

Comment: The zoomlevel shall remain the same, it is just the layer/infobox that shall appear so it is visible.

Comment: try to add a fixed value to the lat and ling of the marker like 0.0004 or 0.00004

Comment: that may depend upon your zoom level also (you are correct)

Comment: I have tried making a dynamic factor on half of the zoom level, but it looks like it isn't enough. I think that the factor is also dependent on the lat and long, and now I think it is getting complex :-|

Comment: yes both depend each other